# I am trying to compare the local storage value with the index of an array

Tags: angular

```
public getCountriesForBKVSVerification(){
    this.blockUserInterface();
  this.authenticationApiService.getCountriesForBKVSVerification().subscribe(success=>{
      this.unblockUserInterface();
      this.countries=success['data'];
      for(let i=0; i<this.countries.length; i++){
   if(localStorage.getItem('countryCode')==this.countries[i['countryCode']){

          this.router.navigate (['login']);
          break;
        } else{
          let type = localStorage.getItem("type")
          if(type == '4'){
            this.redirectUrl = this.prepareRedirectUrlFromLocalStorageForType4({error: true,
            errormessage: 'country code is not of valid format.'});
            const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { queryParams: {redirectUrl : this.redirectUrl ,
            errormessage: 'Invalid Wallet Address Attach Request.'} };
            this.router.navigate(['bkvs-verification-error'], navigationExtras);
            return this.redirectUrl;
          }
          this.redirectUrl = this.prepareRedirectUrlFromLocalStorage({error: true,
          errormessage: 'Country code is not of valid format.'});
          const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { queryParams: {redirectUrl : this.redirectUrl ,
          errormessage: 'Invalid Social KYC Verfication Request.'} };
          this.router.navigate(['bkvs-verification-error'], navigationExtras);
        }
      }
    }, error=>{
      this.unblockUserInterface();
    })
  }
```

In this method, I am fetching the list of countries and somewhere I am storing the country code in local storage from some or other URL. So in an if condition I am checking that local storage country code with the index of the country array. It is always comparing with the first index of the country array.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: It seems that the comparison is not happening properly, can you post the `this.countries` object in the question also?

Comment: Is `countryCode` a string in both localstorage and array?

Comment: @Arikael, type won't be a problem in this case as the compartor used there isn't `===` but `==`. No type comparison will be applied. (Even if I recommand not to do so)

Comment: unless one of it is an object, for example :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.countries[i['countryCode']
```

`i` is the current index in your loop. The above line of code is using `i` as an array. There is no property `countryCode` in `i` as it is a number.

You probably need to do something like:

```
this.countries[i]['countryCode']
```

Moreover, as I remember, localstorage works with strings. Be careful with type comparison.